# De arreglo de numeros, obtener matriz de O y X

Tags: java, array, matriz

Necesito saber resolver este algoritmo.
Una Matriz de 10 elementos que representan una matriz 4x4
Hay una matriz con 10 elementos.

Cada 2 elementos de la matriz corresponden a un movimiento, el primero en el eje horizontal y el segundo en el eje vertical.

El número indica las unidades a mover y el signo la dirección (positivo para derecha o abajo, negativo para izquierda o arriba)

Por ejemplo, para la matriz:

myArray = {1,2, -1,1,0,1,2, -1, -1, -2}

La X se moverá una unidad hacia la derecha y dos hacia abajo, luego una unidad hacia la izquierda y otra hacia abajo, y así sucesivamente.

El programa a escribir debe imprimir la posición final de la X.
Para representar los lugares donde no está la X, use la letra O.

Si la instrucción obliga a la X a salir del área 4x4, la X permanecerá en el borde, sin salir.

Resultado de la matriz myArray:

OXOO 
OOOO 
OOOO 
OOOO

```
public class Main {

  myArray = {1,2, -1,1,0,1,2, -1, -1, -2}

     public static void main(String args[]) {
          
    }
}
```

Comment: _Intenta hacerlo_, con una variable entero x , y. Y con un bucle recorre el array que determina que variable será aumentada o disminuida de acuerdo con la posicion.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado hasta ahorita?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## LA salida estaba correcta el problema era al imprimir los bloques de x no se ##
        int masusado,sumado, suma ,posicion,s,o= 0;
        masusado = 0;
        sumado = 0;
        int n = myarray.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            s = myarray[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (myarray[j] != s)
                {
                    suma = s + myarray[j];
               //se agrega validacion en el if para evitar que se repitan resultados de la suma
                    if (suma == 10  && ( masusado != myarray[j]  && sumado != s))
                    {
                        masusado = s;
                        sumado = myarray[j];
                        Console.WriteLine(s + " " + myarray[j]);
                    }
                }

               
            }
        }
```

Comment: Las ediciones de las preguntas/respuestas son para mejorarlas, no para cambiar completamente el sentido de las mismas. En cuanto a esta respuesta: lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para corregir el formato y explicar cómo responde este código a la pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Este problema se puede resolver pensando en que los valores del arreglo que nos dan son posiciones en un **plano (2 dimensiones)**, teniendo en cuenta esto se podría pensar que iniciamos en la **posición 0,0**; teniendo en cuenta esto, solo debemos ir sumando o restando las posiciones que nos dan, y luego graficar en la poscionon que queda al final.

código:

declaramos unas variables globales que nos identifiquen en que posición estamos, y iniciamos en la posición 0,0.

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
```

recorremos en arreglo sumando y restando en cada coordenada respectivamente(*avanzamos de 2 en dos y asignamos cada valor a cada coordenada X y Y*):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i+=2){
        x = x + myArray[i];
        y = y + myArray[i + 1];
    }
```

Por ultimo, graficamos la figura según la posición que hallamos anteriormente:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++){
        for (int j= 0; j < 4 ;j++){
            if(i == x && j == y){
                System.out.print("X");
            }else {
                System.out.print("O");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**PD/NOTA:** Creo que hay un fallo en tu salida, haciendo el seguimiento, del ejercicio, con la entrada me da como respuesta la siguiente matriz:

```
OOOO
OXOO
OOOO
OOOO
```

Comment: Las respuestas en las que pones código, y no explicas que es lo que hace, no son bienvenidas. Por otra parte, en SO no se hacen Tareas, por lo que no son bienvenidas las respuestas a las preguntas del tipo: ¿alguien me hace esto?

Comment: @Maidagan gracias por tu apreciación, ya realice las modificaciones explicándome mejor, espero que puedas cambiar tu puntuacion.